# Slider в WPF

Tags: c#, slider, wpf

как сделать слайдер в WPF так, что бы разметка у него начиналась не с 0 и до 100 например, а наоборот, с 100 до 0.  Пробывал отобразить зеркально, но это совсем не то, так как цифры не очень смотрятся симпатично задом наперед.

Answer (score 3):

У меня прекрасно сработало [`IsDirectionReversed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.isdirectionreversed.aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="SliderBackwards.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider x:Name="slider"
                IsDirectionReversed="True"
                TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="10"
                Maximum="100" Minimum="0" LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```